# How to structure my DB for storing user's behavior (follow, favorite...) of my website

Tags: php, sql, database, web, storage

I'm building a website that contains articles, these articles won't be shown until the user is logged in, I'm planning to add two buttons, the first one is called "follow this article", the second is meant to make the article as a favourite. My question is how can I structure that in my database?

Should I just add a table that contains `id_article`, `id_user`, `followed(1 or 0)` and `favourite (1 or 0)`, or is there another solution that would let me economize more memory space?

NOTE: My website will have lots of articles that will be visited by a lot of users.

Comment: Your suggested design is good.  Articles to Users is many-to-many (as I understand from your description) and I assume an article can be a favourite only if it is also followed.  The size of this relationship table will be tiny compared with the size of the articles, surely?  So why worry about it?  How many articles and users are you expecting to have?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was hopping to find an optimised solution if possible because I'm expection thousands of articles and hundreds of users.

Comment: What brand of database are you using?  All the leading ones would deal with these volumes with no trouble.  I have databases with a few million rows in the biggest table on my laptop.  Hopefully you'll be using a UNIX server with more capacity than my laptop.  My tables are much wider than your relationship table, and they work fine.  If you have a million relationships and the ids are integers and the "followed" and "favorite" are single bytes you've got 10MB of data.  That will be in memory most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make two separate relations: `articles_followed (id, id_article, id_user)` and `articles_favourite (id, id_article, id_user)`. This will give you enough flexibility in:

- adding new attributes, specific for each relation,
- sharding your database (at some point): it'd be easier to move one relation from another since they are not depending on each other,
- concurrent update: you can use separate locks on these two, in addition, you'll have fewer issues with transaction visibility,
- you don't need to keep `is_followed` or `is_favourite` flag: if there's an entry, then it means that article is followed (once unfollowed, simply remove the line)

Think about your domain classes structure -- which option would be more convenient to code? I bet, in case of two separate relations, it would be clearer.

Comment: If an article can be a favorite without being followed (and, obviously, I think) can be followed without being a favorite then I agree that two relationship tables would be better.  Don't add attributes you don't need though.  If you don't care about the dates, don't include them.  You can always add them later if that becomes a requirement.

Comment: Agreed @Ron Ballard, I've removed dates since they're not required by default.

Comment: thank youuu a lot for your help... I think creating two tables is the best solution,

Comment: @khadija.EL glad to help. Please consider upvoting / marking as answer if that helps :)